# Angular2 simple application to print My First Angular 2 App but getting error?

Tags: angular

I have written one program to print "My First Angular 2 App", but unable to proceed with output.
Kindly suggest where am doing mistake.

environment_app.component.ts

```
import { AnotherComponent } from './anotherComponent.component';
import {component,view} from "angular2/core";
@Component({
selector:'my-app'
template:'<h2>My First Angular 2 App</h2>'
})
export  class AppComponent{
}
```

environment_main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser/index"
import {AppComponent} from "./environment_app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html

```
<html >
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './angular2-demo/app' }
      });
      System.import('app/environment_main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-demo/app/environment_main.ts
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-demo/app/environment_main.ts
    at o (system.src.js:4597)
    at XMLHttpRequest.I.s.onreadystatechange [as _onreadystatechange] (system.src.js:4597)
    at Zone.run (angular2-polyfills.js:1243)
    at XMLHttpRequest.zoneBoundFn (angular2-polyfills.js:1220)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some changes I made to make it work:

environment_app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core"; // capitalized 'Component'
@Component({
    selector:'my-app'
    template:'<h2>My First Angular 2 App</h2>'
})
export  class AppComponent{
}
```

environment_main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser" // removed '/index'
import {AppComponent} from "./environment_app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html:

```
<html >
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {
          main: './environment_main.ts',
          defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }},
        map: { 'app': './src' }
      });
      System.import('app')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/ZH7hUzb32yLJukRK0eFV/)

Comment: Thanks for you solution.application Running successful.